How does Keychain Access on MacOS recognize an EV certificate from a USB dongle?
I have an EV certificate on a USB dongle that I would like to use to code sign on MacOS (Ventura).
I installed the SafeNet client for the latest version of Mac from this website: https://knowledge.digicert.com/general-information/how-to-download-safenet-authentication-client
However, after running the client and plugging in the dongle, security find-identities still finds 0 valid identities, and I'm unable to sign using electron-builder.
Using Keychain Access, I can see that the certificate does not appear in the default or system keychains. I can't export the certificate manually into the keychain because it would not have the private key.
On Windows, trying to sign (using electron-builder) with the dongle plugged in would call the SafeNet client and automatically prompt for a password.
Is the SafeNet client supposed to automatically add a new keychain that would contain the identity?
